# Scrapy: How to visit several subpages and extract all the text?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I would like to perform three simple tasks that should work for most of the pages.

- Get all the links on the main page https://www.stadt-koeln.de/politik-und-verwaltung/stadtentwicklung/
- Visit the extracted subpages (e.g. https://www.stadt-koeln.de/politik-und-verwaltung/stadtentwicklung/heliosgelaende)
- Just get all the text found on the subpages

My approach is:

```
import scrapy

class StadtKoelnSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stadt_koeln"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['http://www.stadt-koeln.de/politik-und-verwaltung/stadtentwicklung/']

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # 1. Get all links 
        for url in response.xpath('body//a/@href').getall():

            # 2. Visit each subpage 
            yield scrapy.Request(url.get(), callback=self.parse_subpage)

    def parse_subpage(self, response):
        # 3. Get text on each subpage 
        text = response.xpath("//p/text()").extract()
       
        yield {
            'Subpage_Text': text
        }
```

No output is generated. Any idea how to make this work? There are several ways to follow links in Scrapy, but I didn't find a working example for my case.

I also get an error. I guess it means that only a part of the url is extracted and not the complete one.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrapy` `crawl` spider. See sample below. Please note that this will return all the text in all the elements on the page

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class StadtKoelnSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'stadt_koeln'
    allowed_domains = ['www.stadt-koeln.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.stadt-koeln.de/politik-und-verwaltung/stadtentwicklung/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"politik-und-verwaltung\/stadtentwicklung"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        all_text = response.xpath("//*/text()").getall()
        yield {
            "Subpage_Text": " ".join(all_text)
        }
```

Comment: It seems that it visits all subpages on each subpage? For me it would be enough visiting only Level 2 which comes after the start_url.

Comment: The `allow` argument accepts any regex pattern. So you can put any valid regex and it will follow it. I have edited the answer so that it only follows links that start with `politik-und-verwaltung/stadtentwicklung`

Comment: I if use your solution I get ~150 results. Some of them contain links that shouldn't be allowed regarding your allow rule, e.g. https://www.stadt-koeln.de/artikel/63625/index.html or https://www.stadt-koeln.de/politik-und-verwaltung/stadtentwicklung/gestaltungshandbuch

Comment: I guess I have the solution. I have to set custom_settings = {'DEPTH_LIMIT': '1'} to avoid going too deep into subpages of subpages.